# Want to check if user already exist MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

my promise always reject even tho the _name i pass in parameters is not always the same as one in the collection any help would be much appreciated
Thanks!

```js
    myCheckUser(_name) {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            self.db.collection("USER").find({ "username": _name }, { $exists: true }).toArray(function    (err, doc) //find if a value exists
            {
                console.log("DOC USERNAME: " + doc.username);
                if (doc) //if it does
                {
                    reject("Found user");
                    console.log(doc.username); // print out what it sends back
                }
                else // if it does not 
                {
                    console.log("Not in docs");
                    resolve("Not found continue logic!")
                }
            }
            )
        });
    };
```

Comment: Why are you rejecting if its found? And why are you console logging after your reject?

Comment: `toArray` means that `doc` will be an array of found documents. Try using the `findOne` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to resolve the promise if data is found and reject the promise. I have corrected your code below:

```js
    myCheckUser(_name) {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            self.db.collection("USER").find({ "username": _name }, { $exists: true }).toArray(function    (err, doc) //find if a value exists
            {
                if (doc && doc.length) //if it does
                {
                    console.log(doc); // print out what it sends back
                    resolve("Found user");
                }
                else // if it does not 
                {
                    console.log("Not in docs");
                    reject("Not found continue logic!")
                }
            }
            )
```